# Java Swing component freezes after running for a few days

Tags: java, swing, java-threads

so we built this internal tool running 24/7 on a VM as daemon, doing some jobs on a worker thread and also built a simple swing GUI for our own convenience that informs us of progress, any problems etc.

The problem is that after running for a few days, the GUI can completely freeze, meaning no more updates, no responsiveness on the scrollbar or window buttons, and if you try to resize the window, the resized portion blacks out.

The worker thread keeps working without a hiccup on the background and keeps logging its work.

I've also attached a debugger to the JVM in order to see if I can understand what is happening, but if  I try to access the component and invoke any method on it (e.g.  .getName(); or anything) the debugger hangs forever trying to evaluate.

As far as I know, all GUI operations need to be on the EDT thread, and all interactions with the component happen through the #appendTextToGui methods which uses the EDT.
The worker thread that calls #appendTextTextToGui is a java.lang.Thread not a SwingWorker if that makes a difference.
Finally, that Thread is calling an external python process with the Java ProcessBuilder, and any output from the python script is piped to the java InputStream and sent to #appendTextToGui

```
public class ProgressGUI extends JFrame {
    private static ProgressGUI instance;
    static JTextPane textpane;
    private StyleContext context;
    private String previousMessage;

    public static ProgressGUI getProgressPanel() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ProgressGUI();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ProgressGUI() {
        LimitedSizeDocument document = new LimitedSizeDocument();
        textpane = new JTextPane(document);
        textpane.setFont(textpane.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
        textpane.setEditable(false);
        textpane.setOpaque(false);
        context = new StyleContext();

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(instance, "Exit request. Are you sure you want to close this worker?", "Confirm Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    if(MailboxProcessor.isProcessorRunning()) {
                        MailboxProcessor.requestShutdown();
                    }
                    else{
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        this.getContentPane().add(getContentPanel(textpane));
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(new Dimension(1400, 800));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Style getTextStyle(Color color) {
        if (context.getStyle(color.toString()) == null) {
            // build a style and set some style properties
            Style newStyle = context.addStyle(color.toString(), null);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(newStyle, color);
            return newStyle;
        }
        return context.getStyle(color.toString());
    }

    private JPanel getContentPanel(JTextComponent textComponent) {
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Image backGroundImage = new ImageIcon(FolderStructure.CONFIG_FOLDER + "inter.png").getImage();

        JViewport viewport = new JViewport() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g); //initialize the default behaviour of the graphics
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE); //change the color of the background of the graphic context
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

                // Paint image
                if (backGroundImage != null) {
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create(); //create copy of the original graphic (that would be the bare background and TextPane)
                    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f)); //any new graphic that is now added (our image) is painted with SRC_OVER on top of the original graphic, and with transparency 0.5f
                    g2d.drawImage(backGroundImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
                    g2d.dispose();
                }
            }
        };


        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textComponent, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        jScrollPane.setViewport(viewport);
        jScrollPane.setViewportView(textComponent);

        //add AdjustmentListener to implement autoscrolling when the scrollbar is at the bottom and not getting adjusted by the user
        jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
            BoundedRangeModel brm = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel();
            boolean wasAtBottom = true;

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!brm.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                            if (wasAtBottom) {
                                brm.setValue(brm.getMaximum());
                            }
                        } else {
                            wasAtBottom = ((brm.getValue() + brm.getExtent()) == brm.getMaximum());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        jPanel.add(jScrollPane);
        return jPanel;
    }

    public void appendTextToGUI(String str) {
        appendTextToGUI(str, Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void appendTextToGUI(String str, Color color) {
        if (str.equals(previousMessage)) return; //prevent spam when checking for new emails many times
        previousMessage = str;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { //GUI modification need to run on EDT
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Document document = textpane.getDocument();
                    document.insertString(document.getLength(), str + System.lineSeparator(), getTextStyle(color));
                    ProgressGUI.this.revalidate();
                    ProgressGUI.this.repaint();
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    Provider.getLogger().info(e.getMessage() + " for string " + str);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Limited size Document class was created to keep the size of the Text Pane of the constantly running workers in check
     */
    private class LimitedSizeDocument extends DefaultStyledDocument {
        private int MAX_DOC_SIZE = 100000;
        @Override
        public void insertString(int offs, String additionalString, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
            // Calculate the number of characters that will exceed the maximum size
            int excess = (getLength() + additionalString.length()) - MAX_DOC_SIZE;
            if (excess > 0) {
                // If the inserted text exceeds the maximum size, discard the oldest characters
                int removeCount = Math.min(offs, excess);
                super.remove(0, removeCount);
                offs = offs - removeCount;
            }
            // Insert the new text
            super.insertString(offs, additionalString, a);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you spot anything that would cause such a problem?

I made a quick stress test bombarding the GUI with updates in a short time but couldn't reproduce the problem

```
    @Ignore
    @Test
    public void testSTRESSProgressGUI() throws BadLocationException, InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
        ProgressGUI progressGUI = ProgressGUI.getProgressPanel();
        progressGUI.setVisible(true);

        String str1 = "progressing...";
        String str2 = "finished";
        while(true){
            progressGUI.appendTextToGUI(str1 + str2 + new Random().nextInt(((int) Instant.now().getEpochSecond()))+ str1+str1+str1+str1+str1+str1+str1 + str2 + new Random().nextInt(((int) Instant.now().getEpochSecond()))+ str1+str1+str1+str1+str1+str1+str1 + str2 +str1+str1+new Random().nextInt(((int) Instant.now().getEpochSecond()))+str1+str1+str1+str1);
            progressGUI.appendTextToGUI("\uD83E\uDD91 Stalking for new emails... \uD83E\uDD91 ", new Color(0, 185, 0));
            progressGUI.appendTextToGUI("\uD83C\uDF89OCR batch finished!\uD83C\uDF89" + System.lineSeparator(), Color.MAGENTA);
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    }
```

Unlikely but is it possible that the component could be affected by the VM not having a screen to display most of the time(only shown when we remotely connect to it)?

Comment: Quite possibly a memory leak. Maybe look into using a memory profiler tool?

Comment: Well after lots of testing and carefully checking the code, it seems this wasn't a problem with the code at all but a problem with the resources. The VM was a little low on memory and disk space was getting filled to the brim on occasion having 5MB of disk left. We applied more resources and haven't encountered the problem again.